# Requesting tips - Sound/foley workshop without software

Tags: sound, foley, tips, beginner

I would need some help with ideas for a **workshop in sound design for beginners**. I'm working at a game company and my boss overheard me talking about **foley** and decided he wants me to hold a fun workshop for the company (we are about 20 people). The problem is, we don't have any software or other tools for making digital audio and the participants knows basically nothing about sound.

I would really appreciate some ideas for a short workshop (around 1 - 3 hours) for beginners that **doesn't require software** or expensive tools and that has a focus on a **fun and creative experience** more than education.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you want to actually record something during the workshop, or just kind of "go through the steps" and mime it? Also, do YOU have any software you can use, on a laptop or something?

Answer (score 1):

- a box of sand
- 2 coconut shells
- a white cabbage
- a balloon
- a pane of glass
- a piece of expanded polystyrene
- a side of ham [or bag of sand]
- a hammer & a blunt chef's vegetable knife ...

hours of fun.

You might want some footage they can see the effect on.
20 mins of Game of Thrones with the sound turned off could use all those.